# Customize javascript Date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple code that echos the current Hour+Minute+Date as one number sequence.

I need to add 1 to all the numbers outputted, individually.

Example: If the current time and date is: 22321512 then i need jQuery to output: 33432623.

My knowledge in jQuery is pretty slim, How can this be achieved?

HTML:

```
<span id="date"></span>
```

Code:

```
var now = dateFormat(new Date(), "HHMMddmm");
$('#date').append(now);
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, wouldn't you want `23331613` as the output?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the following roughly:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var myDate = new Date(currentDate.getYear() + 1, currentDate.getMonth() + 1, currentDate.getDay() + 1);

alert(myDate.getTime());
```

Should solve your problem.

Comment: Ill try this one once i get home, Though how can i attach it to a span...and not an alert?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to merely increment each unit by 1 and let the JavaScript engine advance the date and time on overflow, then [Captain John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1727038/captain-john)'s answer will work perfectly.
 This means that, for example, if this routine were to be run at 11:59 PM on December 31, your output would be `00000100`.

If you want each unit to be incremented by 1 without the date being advanced, you will have to stop relying on [Steven Levithan's [excellent] `dateFormat` library](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) and do it yourself:

```
var now = new Date(),
    hours = now.getHours() + 1,     // add 1 hour
    minutes = now.getMinutes() + 1, // add 1 minute
    date = now.getDate() + 1,       // add 1 day
    month = now.getMonth() + 1,     // add 1 month
    padLeft = function (val) {      // make a formatter
        while (val.length < 2) {
            val = '0' + val;        // string is less than 2 characters, pad left side with '0'
        }
        return val;                 // return formatted string
    },
    formatted = padLeft(hours) + padLeft(minutes) + padLeft(date) + padLeft(month);
$('#date').append(formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting number length as string you can easily sum 1 to each number.

- The result is given as timestamp
- To get Date object, use new Date(result);

  var now = new Date().getTime(); // 22321512 on your example

  // Answer
  var result = 0;
  var str = now.toString();
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
     result += Math.pow(10, i);
  }
  result += now; // Ex.: 22321512 + 11111111